# Informaiton directory under home/user/

Tags: home-directory

I have a folder named Information under home/user in ubuntu. It seems to have some content from an NTFS drive that I have. My questions are these:

1. Is this a system created folder or created by some application.
2. Is it safe to delete it?

[Informmation folder under /home/user](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y9FJh.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your screenshot it's under `home/user/<some_user>` where "some_user" is your user or other. Under `/home/user` there should be only folders with a username. Only one with your username if you're the single user.

It's not a typical folder crated by the system and probably not created by any application so it is likely to have been created by you or someone using your account.

> Is it safe to delete it?

It's safe to delete but it's up to you to check whether or not you need its contents.